# How to define attribution of attribution in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to make an attribution of an attribution in python.
Is there a way to do so:

```
  class Foo():
     def __init__(self, x, y):
         self.x = x
         self.x.y = y
```

I have no idea how to do it, I checked for some examples. But I have not found any example similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly clear what you need you can do something like this (for example):

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, y=None):
       self.y = y

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
       self.x = x
       self.x.y = y

if __name__ == '__main__':
     x = Bar()
     y = 1
     foo = Foo(x,y)
```

Comment: I tried your way, x = Foo(1,2) but program throw an AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'y'

Comment: This is correct, you cannot attribute to an arbitrary data type. The data type must have a parameter called `y` which `1` - `int` does not have.

Comment: @Radekhofman that is only true of your object has `__slots__`  ( which `int` does) Otherwise you can assign an attribute to an object dynamically